# Manage Simultaneous calls to a REST Service without Duplicate an ID in JAVA

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, jmeter

I´m build a REST service through Spring and Swagger with CMIS Protocol in Maven. My services works well until the moment when I´m doing simultaneous calls through Jmeter to stress the system. Context: the service get an ID from an ID creator to generate a node in Alfresco. The id cannot be repeated in the system. this id creator take the last created node and sum +1. I tried with Thread.sleep and TimeUnit. The Jmeter Answer in 10 calls in one sec that the Node was created 10 times with the same ID.

Extract of current code: Controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Crea un Tipo de documento")
@RequestMapping(value = "/create2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseMessage createTypeDocument2(@RequestParam String description) throws InterruptedException {                 
    return typeDocumentService.createTypeDocument(description);     
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
public ResponseMessage createTypeDocument(String description) throws InterruptedException {     
    Session session = obtieneSesion();
    int id = this.idCreator2();
    int aux = 0; 
    if(searchDocuments(id)==null) {
        aux=0;
    }else {
        aux = Integer.parseInt(searchDocuments(id).getProperty("bc:id").getValueAsString());
    }
    ResponseMessage rm = new ResponseMessage();

    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(new Random().nextInt(500));
    Thread.sleep(1000);     
    if(id != aux ) {        
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("SSS");
        Date date = new Date();
        String nombre = sdf.format(date.getTime());                 
        DocumentTypeDTO docFilter = new DocumentTypeDTO();
        Folder root = (Folder) session.getObjectByPath("/DataList-BCH");            
        HashMap<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        metadata.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "***************");
        metadata.put(PropertyIds.NAME, nombre);
        metadata.put("bc:id", id);
        metadata.put("bc:available", activo);   
        metadata.put("bc:description", description);    

        Document newDoc = root.createDocument(metadata, null, null);

        docFilter.setId( Integer.parseInt(newDoc.getProperty("bc:id").getValueAsString()));
        docFilter.setDescription(newDoc.getProperty("bc:description").getValueAsString());
        docFilter.setUuid(newDoc.getId().replaceAll(";1.0", "").replace("workspace://SpacesStore/", ""));   

        rm.setMensaje("Exitoso");
        rm.setCodigo(200);
        rm.setObjeto(docFilter);
        return rm;
    }else {
        rm.setCodigo(-1);
        rm.setMensaje("La ID ya existe");
        return rm;
    }       
}
```

SearchDocument method if the object is not found return null. I try multiple options without results, for that reason I need your help to resolve it. Thanks in Advice

RESOLVED IN STACKOVERFLOW IN SPANISH:
[RESOLVED](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/152847/controlar-llamadas-simultaneas-a-un-servicio-rest-sin-que-se-duplique-la-id-en-j/152908?noredirect=1#comment286829_152908)